# How to add a node with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I tried to add a new node following the [example](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detail.html#round-trip-including-comments) but:

```
myitems = ruamel.yaml.load(inp, ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)
myitems['abc'].append('test')
```

gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "item_updater.py", line 148, in <module>
    myitems['wohnung'].append('test')
AttributeError: 'CommentedMap' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I am using ruamel.yaml v0.13.7

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you use version 0.8?

Comment: Version 0.8 of what?

Comment: I am using ruamel.yaml v0.13.7 (that is the latest version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error doesn't come from the example you indicated, as in the `inp` of the example there is no `wohnung` that shows up in your error.

You probably forgot a `-` somewhere:

```
wohnung:
   a: 1
```

instead of:

```
wohnung:
- a: 1
```

only on the latter you can append using `myitems['wohnung'].append('test')`.

The example works, but without showing your real YAML input it is difficult to see what is the exact cause of your error.

Comment: Ok, reading that example I was under the impression not only ```data['abc'].append('b')```would work, but ```data['xyz'].append('b')```would work too.

Comment: The toplevel of that YAML file is a mapping. Its key 'abc' has a value that is a sequence. This gets loaded into Python as a—subclass of—`list` (with first element the `'a'`). The key `xyz` of the toplevel has a value that is again a mapping. This gets loaded as a—subclass of—`dict` (with key/value pairs `('a', 1)`, `('b', 2)`, etc.) You can append to the `list`, but not to the `dict`

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks for the clarification. - In general I have some difficulties understanding the details of the yaml implementation in python. PyYAML and ruamel.yaml are not documented that extensively.

Comment: @msinn WRT the documentation of ruamel.yaml you are right, it is was often an afterthought, if thought about at all. Feel free to ask here on [so] for clarifications, but please make sure you include your exact input (minimalized). That is why I "complained" that it is unclear where "`wohnung`" came from.